# buckets.hpp missing from boost 1.64

Tags: boost, header-files

I need to include `boost/unordered/detail/buckets.hpp`, which is available, for example, in boost 1.61.

I installed boost 1.64 and it is not available anymore, in the sense that there is no such file under the folder `boost/unordered/detail/`.

Am I doing something wrong? Should I look for the same file anywhere else?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean "I need to"? Everything under `detail` folder or namespaces is an implementation detail. It's also not documented for this reason, and you should not depend on it.

The implementation detail changed, and hence the code depending on the (undocumented) non-interface details broke.

Your options are to figure out what goal was achieved by the depending code and fix it to work with the new version, or to stay with the old version.